# res.sendFile not rendering html

Tags: html, node.js, express

I am trying to render HTML with res.sendFile using absolute path but it is sending encoded HTML in a pre tag so the response shows HTML unrendered in a pre tag.
Here is my express code

```
app.get('/', (req,res) =>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/a.html');
    });
```

and here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I am Html</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the result when I navigate to localhost:8800/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>I am Html</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

It prints the html as it is without rendering it.

Comment: Are you explictly setting headers somewhere for the responses. For example in a global middleware with something like `res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");` which could be a cause. Although pointless (cause supported version came 5 years ago), u are using express version > `4.8.0` ?

Comment: Actually,Yes.This was the problem all along. Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

You need to use res.render() to actually render the html.

Comment: If I am not wrong res.render is used for template engines

Answer (score -1):

I can't post a comment because I don't have enough reputation, but what I was going to say is that I ran your code on my system (OSX Mojave 10.14.6, Node v12.13.0, latest versions of Firefox and Chrome) with some additions to make it work (posted below), and didn't run into your problem. Perhaps you have some other code or middleware that you haven't posted. Also, you are correct that `res.render` is for templates.

```html
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/a.html');
    // better to use the path API, but both work
    // res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'a.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

The HTML is the same. Folder structure is:

```html
.
├── app.js
├── a.html
```

Could you post more details?

Comment: I figured it out. It was a header middleware problem